# How to connect my own pc mysql from gcp app engine?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy demo on Net so I use gcp's app engine to deploy my web,
but gcp' cloud sql is too expensive.

I'm considering use app engine connect mysql to my own pc with tcp and ip,
but it's not work.

this is my mysql.yaml

```
db:
  username: "myusername"
  password: "mypassword"
  network: "tcp"
  server: "mypcip"
  port: 3306
  database: "demo"
```

It is works when the db.server is "localhost", and run on local,but I want it be public,
how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If Cloud SQL is "too" expensive, you have 2 solutions:

- Firstly, use Cloud SQL, but with shared core VM, in the customization part. It's about 2€ per month
  [image: List item]
- Secondly, you can leverage the [Compute ENgine free tiers](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute), and install MySQL on it

---

If you are in the cloud, stay in the cloud and don't depends on SPoF resources